# Is it possible to use Windows VisualSVN repository with a MAC Client

Tags: javascript, c#, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have set up a windows VsiualSVN reporitory on my windows server.

I connect to the repository using TortoiseSVN on my Windows client

However a collegue has a MAC, is there a MAC SVN client that i can use to connect to the Windows VisualSVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a MAC SVN client that i can use to connect to the Windows
>   VisualSVN?

It doesn't really matter if underlying OS on your SVN server is Win, OSX, Unix or something else. You can use these MAC SVN clients to connect to SVN server:

- svnX - https://code.google.com/p/svnx/
- Versions - http://versionsapp.com/
- XCode - https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: That was the answer i was hoping for , thank you for your help i will try one of them out. Thank you Ivan